# CloudFormation: Unable to access the EC2 instance created using CloudFomation through public DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I am deploying an EC2 instance using CloudFormation. Then I installed apache and uploaded the files to EC2 instance after deployment. When the instance is deployed I cannot access it using public DNS from browser.

This is my EC2 instance resource and its security group.

```
WebServerInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      ImageId:
        Fn::FindInMap:
          - AWSRegionArch2AMI
          - Ref: AWS::Region
          - Fn::FindInMap:
              - AWSInstanceType2Arch
              - Ref: InstanceType
              - Arch
      AvailabilityZone: !Select
        - 0
        - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref AWS::Region
  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable HTTP access via port 80
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp:
            Ref: SSHLocation
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
```

When I access it from the browser, it just keeps loading loading and loading. I set the inbound rules on the security group too. What is wrong with it and how can I fix it?

This is my public DNS,
http://ec2-3-{xxx-xxx-xx}.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

This is the Public subnet resource.

```
PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      CidrBlock: !Select [ 0, !Cidr [ !Ref VpcCidr, 12, 8 ] ]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: True
      AvailabilityZone: !Select
        - 0
        - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref AWS::Region
```

There is a route table for public subnet.

[image]

In the internet gateway console, there is only one gateway and which is not attached to the VPC in the template. Can this be the issue?

**Edit**
I got this error

[image]

Comment: Does the subnet have a route table attached with an internet gateway?

Comment: Hi. Do you have full CFN template to show, like last time? This would enable me to launch it it my sandabox and hopefully faster verify the instance conectivity.

Comment: Hi yes. Can we do that in chat?

Comment: I see the issue was solved :-)

Comment: Yes. It has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons outside the security group allowing access. The following should be checked:

Check your instances subnet has a route within its route table for `0.0.0.0/0` which has a destination of a internet gateway.

Each subnet will have an available route table (this will be the default route table if you did not specify one).

This can be completed by using the CloudFormation below

```
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  AttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      InternetGatewayId:
        Ref: InternetGateway    
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId:  
        Ref: myVPC
  Route:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: InternetGateway
    Properties:
       RouteTableId:
         Ref: RouteTable
       DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
       GatewayId:
         Ref: InternetGateway
  SubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId:
        Ref: Subnet
      RouteTableId:
        Ref: RouteTable
```

If you updated the default NACL make sure you added both port 80 and ephemeral ports to the rules.

Make sure apache is running on the host (not just installed). This can be done by running `systemctl start apache` on debian based OS or `systemctl start httpd` on a RHEL based.

Comment: I updated the question to include the screenshot of the route table. Is that the one you are referring to?

Comment: Also, included the internet gateway details. Please, have a look.

Comment: Right yes you'll need to create a new internet gateway (they can only be attached to  a single VPC) and the add it as a route. I've added some CloudFormation to this answer which includes how to create one

Comment: OK. Thanks. I will give it a go.

Comment: DestinationCidrBlock. 0.0.0.0/0 should be fine or does it have to be the same as the one in VPC?

Comment: Also DependsOn: GatewayToInternet. What is GatewayToInternet?

Comment: `0.0.0.0/0` is fine (this is basically saying route all traffic that does not match a more specific route).

Comment: When I deploy, I get, "An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [GatewayToInternet] in the Resources block of the template".

Comment: Ah that should be `InternetGateway`, replace `GatewayToInternet` string with `InternetGateway`

Comment: Hi, I tried and I got the error. I updated your answer to include a screenshot. Please, have a look.

Comment: It did not finish. The command never finished. I had to stop it.

Comment: Also, now it does not allow me to delete that stack. I am now stuck.

Comment: Can you post your cloudformation template, this is normally a AWS CLI error handled badly on the backend of CloudFormation (it’s like it gets caught in a loop). The stuck resource will have an incorrect value for one of its parameters

Comment: Hi, can we do it in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218635/discussion-between-wai-yan-hein-and-chris-williams).

Comment: Hi, I tried the code you posted. It is still not working. It just keeps loading.

Comment: I got it working. EC2 instance is missing this property, SecurityGroupIds. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem have a great day :)